# Solve vectors using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

`(2a+5b)(3a-2b)`, where length of vector `|a| = 3`,length of vector `|b| = 4` and vector between them `φ = 2pi/3`.
I figured out that I perhaps need to use `sympy.expand((2*a+5*b)*(3*a-2*b))` and then `symply.evalf(subs=???)`, however, I have no idea what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be simplified by assuming, for instance,
that `a = [3, 0, 0]` since the direction doesn't matter.

```
N = CoordSys3D('N')

a_x, a_y, a_z = symbols('a_x a_y a_z')
b_x, b_y, b_z = symbols('b_x b_y b_z')

a = a_x*N.i + a_y*N.j + a_z*N.k
b = b_x*N.i + b_y*N.j + b_z*N.k

eq1 = a.dot(a) - 3**2             # ||a|| = 3
eq2 = b.dot(b) - 4**2             # ||b|| = 4
eq3 = a.dot(b) - 3*4*cos(2*pi/3)  # a*b = ||a|| ||b|| cos(phi)

sols = nonlinsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [a_x, a_y, b_x])
sol = list(sols)[0] # first solution

v = (2*a + 5*b).dot(3*a - 2*b)
v.subs({a_x: sol[0], a_y: sol[1], b_x: sol[2]}).simplify()
# >>> -172
```

I think it's enough to solve for 3 of the 6 variables since `a` can
be any direction (2 degrees of freedom), and then `b` can 'rotate' around `a` with one degree of freedom.